# Can you wrap arbitrary elements inside a "figure" to indicate that it's HTML-as-image?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

If you're using div-soup and CSS in a non-semantic way to create a visual picture, does it make sense to wrap it all in a `<figure>` element to indicate that the contents are non-semantic?

More info: I'm using a bunch of nested DIVs and SPANs with inline styles to draw a bar chart. (I know that SVG is a better way to do this, but it's not feasible to make SVG responsive with percentage-based dimensions in the way my design requires.) Separately, I've also made a screenreader-accessible text summary of the chart. But I don't want screenreaders to trip up on the visual version.

Comment: Just curious, wouldn't [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) be easier to use? It also is responsive, so it should not cause any issues even if you are using percentage.

Comment: This project has specific requirements to work without JS. Also the chart renders really nicely with flexbox and percentage widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this is an acceptable use of `figure`.

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is **self-contained** (like a complete sentence) and is
>   typically referenced as **a single unit** from the main flow of the
>   document.

> The element can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams,
>   photos, code listings, etc.

<sub>[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), emphasis mine</sub>

Adding an ARIA role of`img` to the `figure` might improve the markup further.

> An img represents a single graphic within a document, **whether or not
>   it is formed by a collection of drawing objects**.

<sub>[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#img), emphasis mine</sub>